# Light bulbs in a high dimensional grid

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, coding-theory

Consider a $n \times n \times n$ array of light bulbs. In each step, one can flip lights from on to off and off to on along a 1d row in the $x$-, $y$- or $z$-axis.

Suppose one has a configuration that can switch all the lights off. Show that one can do so in $3\text{(# of lights that are on)}/n$ steps.

More generally, for a $d$-dimensional array of light bulbs with width $n$, if one again can flip a 1d row of lights, show that one can switch off in $d\text{(# of lights that are on)}/n$ steps.

===

I’m 90% confident that this is true from examples. Note that this bound is tight in the sense that for all $d$, there exists $n$ and a configuration where one needs to perform $d\text{(# of lights that are on)}/n$ steps. For example, when $n=2$ and 2 lights are on are at $0^d$ and $1^d$, one needs to perform $d$ flips. There are other examples too.

Comment: You are studying the vector subspace of $\mathbf{F}_2^{[n]^d}$ generated by the indicators of the $d n^{d-1}$ lines. Some subset of the generators is a basis, so at least this proves a uniform $d n^{d-1}$ upper bound, which coincides with the worst case of your conjecture.

Comment: Do you ask specifically about $d = 3$ because for $d = 2$ you have a proof?

Comment: For $n = 2$ the bound holds, by the following reasoning. Consider two lights that are on at minimal Hamming distance, say $d' \leq d$. Every flip toggles just two lights, so with a sequence of $d'$ flips we can walk one of these lights over to the other one and annihilate both. We used at most $d$ steps to turn off 2 lights and we didn't change anything else. (Moreover this is sharp only if every pair of lights that are on are at distance $d$, which implies only two lights are on.)

Comment: @SeanEberhard
1, 2) Yes, indeed.
3) Yes, ideally I would like to have results for any n.

Comment: If you have a proof for $d=2$ it would be interesting to see it.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Here is a proof for $d=2$: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gxsvzfkxkvqq

Comment: For those who don't know this is a variation of [Berlekamp switching game](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp_switching_game).

Comment: Just throwing random thoughts. Can we show this using some kind of convexity?? The hope is that this will reduce the problem to "extreme points". But the first question to answer is "is there a sense of convexity in this setting?".